# Concrete Mathematics - Confusion regarding use of Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, discrete-mathematics

In Chapter 3 of *Concrete Mathematics, Second Edition* by Knuth, Graham and Patashnik, the authors prove a property of the ceiling (or floor) function. Here it is:

[image]

In lines 4 to 3 (from the bottom), I believe the Intermediate Value Theorem is used on the interval $[x,\lceil{x}\rceil)$. However, for that, we require the inequality $f(x) \leq \lceil{f(x)}\rceil \leq f(\lceil{x}\rceil)$. But we have $f(x) \leq \lceil{f(x)}\rceil < \lceil{f(\lceil{x}\rceil)}\rceil$.

How can we then apply the IVT?

Comment: I now realized that this question might be a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1859233/592479

Comment: @Maruo The special property holds for $f$ not for the ceiling of $f$.